# Mosquitto Broker ACL pattern and user rules conflict

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, acl, mosquitto

I'm trying to configure ACL for my **Mosquitto Broker** (1.4.15) installed on **Ubuntu** (18.04.5) in such way that:

- Every user get to subscribe and publish to any topic under his user name
- With the exception of admin user, I want him to be able to read and write any topic.

when I type the following in ACL file:

```
pattern readwrite %u/#
```

Every user is able to connect and readwrite to topics under his name (*user/home/kitchen*)

**However** if I add this to ACL file:

```
pattern readwrite %u/#

user admin
topic #
```

No one other than admin user can even **connect** to the broker. Also the admin is given his intended rule to readwrite any topic.

I think the idea can be possible if I code every user separately but given potential huge number of users this is not practical. **Any suggestion to how use pattern and user together**?

Comment: Mosquito 1.4.15 is seriously antique (2018). Please try this with an up-to-date version of Mosquitto, like 2.0.14.

Comment: Would be useful to see the rest of your mosquitto.conf and what you have in the password file as that ACL file works fine with 2.0.14. (As already mentioned you should not be deploying new workloads on v1.4.15 or Ubuntu 18.04.x)

Comment: @hardillb after upgrading bunt and mosquitto, this worked. thx a lot